# tasty pie - Return JSON with non ORM object

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I am new with tasty pie and I am trying to simply return a json structure from my API.

I have the following class:

```
class CaseResource(Resource):
    class Meta:
        authentication = SessionAuthentication()
        resource_name = 'case'
        allowed_methods = ['get']

    def obj_get_list(self, request, **kwargs):
         case = request.GET.get('q')
         if case:
             mycase = connect_and_retrieve_data(request, q)
             return self.create_response(request, {'mycase': mycase})
```

connect_and_retrieve_data is a method that is returning a json_dump for a non ORM object.

When I am sending the GET request in AJAX, I got the following response:

```
NotImplementedError at /mydashboard/api/v1/case/
No exception message supplied
```

The API pointed me to "Using Tastypie With Non-ORM Data Sources", though I was hoping for something less heavy handed.

I guess that I have to overwrite all the methods:

- detail_uri_kwargs
- get_object_list
- obj_get_list
- obj_get
- obj_create
- obj_update
- obj_delete_list
- obj_delete
- rollback

but this looks quite heavy. Is there an other way to do this or using a different method?

Thank you in advance for your help,

Comment: `obj_get_list` is aimed to be called when you perform a GET request.

Comment: Tastypie is intended to build REST style APIs. So you should not send a `POST` request  to `obj_get_list`. With Tastypie your `POST` request is directed to `obj_create `.

Comment: Hi ohrstrom and slackmart, thank you for your update, in that case, I would like to perform the same action with a GET request.

Answer (score -1):

For one single request you could make none RESTful endpoint. This would be not right if you have decided for some reason that your whole service is going to be 100% RESTful.

But, if you are looking for something less heavily try standard Django view:

```
import json

from django.http import (HttpResponse,
                     HttpResponseNotAllowed, HttpResponseForbidden)
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt


@csrf_exempt
def connect_and_retrieve_data(request):
    """
    Docstrings..
    """
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseForbidden(json.dumps({'message': 'User must be authenticated'}),
                                     content_type='application/json')
    if request.method != 'GET':
        return HttpResponseNotAllowed(permitted_methods=('GET',))

    if request.GET.get('q'):
        mycase = connect_and_retrieve_data(request, request.GET.get('q'))
        mycase = json.loads(mycase)
        return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps({'mycase': mycase, 'success': True}),
            content_type='application/json')
    else:
        return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps({'message': 'Missing q param', 'success': False}),
            content_type='application/json')
```

Be aware of that your project might be falling out of control soon if you will get too many undocumented and untested endpoints like this in RESTful API. At some point you might consider something else then RESTful. But if it is not more then 10% of all endpoints and nicely described you will be fine.